# Putting vector inside of a array element

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Is possible to put a vector in the array element a[0],a[1]... (different vector in each a[x])?
And if possible, how do I access one element of the vector in a given a[n]?

Comment: yes, is will be accessed like a[n][i] where i is the index of an element in the vector

Comment: wait, by array you mean static array, in which you want to put dynamic vectors or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the possibilities you have:

```
// Static array of vectors (not a good practice though) 
std::vector<int> vec_array1[size];

// Or dynamic array of vectors (still not very c++ish and error prone)
std::vector<int> *vec_array2;
vec_array = new std::vector<int>[size];

// Or vector of vectors
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec_array3(size);

// Or std::array of vectors (in c++11)
std::array<std::vector<int>, size> *vec_array4;
```

In any case, you can access the vectors using `[]` operator:

```
vec_array[0].push_back(5);
```

And the elements using two `[]` operators like:

```
vec_array[0][2] = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  Here's an example of how to do it.

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, n> array_of_vector;
//add to vector in array
array_of_vector[0].push_back(4);
//access element in vector in array
array_of_vector[0][0]=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
 std::vector< std::vector < type > > a;
```

so, `a[i]` is a `std::vector` as you need.